# Understanding mathematics: Deriving the Q learning Equation.

Tags: probability, machine-learning

I am trying to implement [this](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Edonev/Teaching/WrittenOral/Projects/XintianHan-WrittenAndOral.pdf) article. I have fairly understood the mathematics. But I am unable to understand where the following term comes from. It is located in the middle of page no. 4.

$$v_\pi(s) = \sum_{a \in \mathcal A} \pi(a \mid s) q_{\pi}(s, a)$$

I am not able to understand if it comes from Bayes Theorem or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unpack that, we need some other definitions in the paper:

- $\pi(a \mid s) = \mathbb P \left[ A_t = a \mid S_t = s \right]$
- $q_\pi(s, a) = \mathbb E_\pi \left[ G_t \mid S_t = s, A_t = a \right]$
- $v_\pi(s) = \mathbb E_\pi \left[ G_t \mid S_t = s \right]$

The big idea is to decompose across the possible values of $A_t$:

\begin{align*}
  v_{\pi}(s) &= \mathbb E_\pi \left[ G_t \mid S_t = s \right] \\
  &=\sum_{a \in \mathcal A} \mathbb E_\pi \left[ G_t \mid S_t = s, A_t = a \right] \cdot \mathbb P(A_t = a \mid S_t = s)\\
\end{align*}
This is hopefully intuitively reasonable, but it also kind of begs the question of why it's justified. Here's a more rigorous justification using indicator variables and the definition of conditional expectation:

\begin{align*}
  v_{\pi}(s) &= \mathbb E_\pi \left[ G_t \mid S_t = s \right] \\
  &= \sum_{a \in \mathcal A} \mathbb E_\pi \left[G_t \cdot \textbf 1_{A_t = a} \mid S_t = s\right] \\
&= \sum_{a \in \mathcal A} \sum_{x} x \cdot \mathbb P \left(G_t = x, A_t = a \mid S_t = s\right) & \bigstar \\
&= \sum_{a \in \mathcal A} \sum_{x} x \cdot \frac{\mathbb P \left(G_t = x, A_t = a, S_t = s \right)}{\mathbb P(S_t = s)}\\ 
&= \sum_{a \in \mathcal A} \sum_{x} x \cdot \frac{\mathbb P \left(G_t = x, A_t = a, S_t = s \right)}{\mathbb P(A_t = a, S_t = s)} \cdot \frac{\mathbb P(A_t = a, S_t = s)}{\mathbb P(S_t = s)} \\
&= \sum_{a \in \mathcal A} \sum_{x} x \cdot \mathbb P \left(G_t = x \mid A_t = a, S_t = s \right) \cdot \mathbb P \left(A_t = a \mid S_t = s \right) \\
&= \sum_{a \in \mathcal A} \mathbb P \left(A_t = a \mid S_t = s \right) \cdot \left[ \sum_{x} x P \left(G_t = x \mid A_t = a, S_t = s \right) \right]
\end{align*}

as desired.

(Note: the equality on line $\bigstar$ is just a bit odd, but the idea is: for $x \neq 0$, $G_t \cdot 1_{A_t = a} = x$ holds if and only if $G_t = x$ and $A_t = a$. When $x = 0$, the term vanishes from the sum altogether.)

Comment: You have no idea how much your answer helped me!!! Thanks a ton!!! Many regards!!!

Comment: One thing I would like to ask is how did you come up with the second equation from the first in your derivation section?

Comment: Assuming you mean the line above the starred one: it's a standard decomposition trick. The idea is that if $\mathcal A$ is all the possible values for $a$, then $\sum_{a \in \mathcal A} \textbf 1_{A_t = a} = 1$, because the left side consists of *indicator variables* that are $1$ only on the set where $\{A_t = a\}$, and for a given $\omega$ in the sample space, $A_t = a$ will hold for precisely one $a$.

Comment: Is it something similar to when we find the marginal distribution of y from joint distribution of x,y? $p_Y(y) = \sum_i p(x_i, y) \quad(\text{fix a value of}\ Y\ \text{and sum over possible values of}\ X)$

Comment: Hi, in case you have some free time, could you help me with this question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4422811/384502

Comment: Yes, the decomposition trick is very similar to the marginal / joint distribution idea you cited.

Comment: Thank you sir. Many regards.